# Read Error when loading JSON array in Newtonsoft C#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, list

I'm using the Newtonsoft JSON parser in C#. The JSON seems to be formatted correctly but I'm getting a read error that doesn't make sense. The JSON should deserialize and load into the class instance automatically.

Class:

```
class FilterMatrix {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
}
```

Deserializing code:

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\accounts.json";
FilterMatrix kernel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FilterMatrix>(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
```

JSON file contents:

```
{"Features":[{"ID":0,"ParentID":0},{"ID":0,"ParentID":0}]}
```

Error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'Features', line 1, position 14.'
```

Comment: The error message seems a bit odd but that JSON does not look like it represents a FilterMatrix object

Comment: I just realized that my class needs a Features property. Should it be a collection type? A List?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, at least the structure of the JSON needs to match your class hierarchy. Working example:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(File.ReadAllText("file.json"));
    }

}

public class Root
{
    public List<FilterMatrix> Features { get; set; }
}

public class FilterMatrix
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Gene.

I basically came up with this as I saw  your post. It never donned on me to have multiple classes within a class. I guess I assumed an array of classes would be automatically made :-/

JSON script:

```
{"Features":[{"ID":0,"ParentID":0},{"ID":0,"ParentID":0}]}
```

Deserialization:

```
kernel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FilterMatrix>(File.ReadAllText(fileName));
```

My classes:

```
class FilterMatrix {
    private List<Feature> features = new List<Feature>();  
    public List<Feature> FeaturesList
    {
        get { return features; }
        set { features = value; }
    }
}

class Feature {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
}
```

I access elements by their index:

```
kernel.FeaturesList[0].ID
```